# Leaflet marker example with custom icons - Left click event with Microsoft Edge is not triggered

Tags: javascript, leaflet, click, marker

When working with *L.marker* with custom icons, I noticed that when I add a click event to the markers like

```js
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
        alert('clicked');
    });
```

the "clicked alert" is only triggered when I left click on the icon with Microsoft Edge. Only a right click triggers the event, but also the context menu.

However, when I work with *L.circleMarker*, a left click triggers the event without any problems with Microsoft Edge.

After checking my code, I looked at the sample page (https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/) and found that left-clicking on a marker in the first map with Microsoft Edge does not trigger a popup either.

Is there any way that left clicking on markers with custom icons will trigger the event in Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Works for me, left click on the markers in edge displaying the popups

Comment: Welcome to SO! Works for me as well, checked on Edge 89.0.774.54 (64-bit). If your issue persists, please provide more details about the OS, browser, and make sure you can reproduce it on different machines as well.